# Sending one single email for multiple builders

Tags: buildbot

I am setting up a build environment with a unique master buildbot and multiple buildslaves. I have multiple builders which will run on the available slaves. The builders can be triggered on-force or scheduled to run as nightly builds or can be scheduled to run when some changes are detected.

I have setup a MailNotifier to send the results/status of the builds. This MailNotifier will send one email for each of the builder. What I want to do now is to send a **single** email for multiple builders. For e.g. all the nightly builders after successfully building, trigger some function in master buildbot which will trigger the buildbot to send a **single** email which includes the results of all the nightly builders.

I would like to know whether something like this is possible and whether buildbot provides support to send a single email for multiple builders. If not any pointer how to accomplish this ??

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `buildSetSummary` parameter to `MailNotifier`: if you set this parameter to `True`, it will send a single e-mail listing statuses of all completed builds.

More information: [Buildbot Manual](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-statustargets.html#mailnotifier-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite a while since you asked this but just in case you still need an answer, look at the settings for buildbot's [MailNotifier](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/0.8.7p1/full.html#mailnotifier-arguments). The default behaviour is to send an e-mail for each builder, so you have to specify which ones you're interested in using the `builders` argument (scroll down the page):

> `builders` (list of strings). A list of builder names for which mail
>   should be sent. Defaults to None (send mail for all builds). Use
>   either builders or categories, but not both.

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Create a TriggerableScheduler with all your builders in builderNames.  Then, create a "super" builder with the following 2 steps:

1. trigger the new TriggerableScheduler with waitForFinish=True
2. send the email